# jQuery mobile Multi Page Internal

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

*I've had a search, all references to multi page that might come close to helping me are years old and an ancient version of jqm.*

For clarification: Internal page is a page hosted in a separate file but on the same server, in the same directory as my index.html.  An external page would be hosted in a separate file on a different server/domain.

My goal: I have an app which as a single document multi-page which appears fat. It has about 20 pages (with the div-data-role=page). I thought of placing most of these pages into internal pages (thus separate files hosted at the same location as the main index.html page).

This piece guides me...

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

> To enable animated page transitions, all links that point to an external page (ex. products.html) will be loaded via Ajax. To do this unobtrusively, the framework parses the link's href to formulate an Ajax request (Hijax) and displays the loading spinner. All this is done automatically by jQuery Mobile.
>
> If the Ajax request is successful, the new page content is added to
>   the DOM, all mobile widgets are auto-initialized, then the new page is
>   animated into view with a page transition.

So... Perhaps I have misunderstood having internal pages within jqm - I am getting a page refresh when I expected my page to be loaded via ajax.

I have two pages, an index.html page which has an anchor to m1.html. I would expect that when I am viewing index.html and I click on m1.html, that the URL would magically pull the contents of my div-data-role=page into my index.html DOM and give me a URL similar to index.html#m1

Instead, when I click on the m1 link, I am getting a page refresh and the URL changes to m1.html

Can someone clarify my (mis)understanding?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />

    <link href="/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> 
    <link href="/css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <script src="/jq/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/jq/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <div data-role="page" id="Menu">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-title center">
            Main PAGE
        </div>
        <div id="MainContent">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="m1.html">m1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**m1.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="m1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="ui-title center"> ONE
    </div>
    <div id="MainContent">
        <h1>one</h1>
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#Menu">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `rel="external"` on the link. That tells jQM to NOT use AJAX when loading pages.

See more info here:  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions, the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax behavior.

Comment: I edited/removed the rel="external" and host the documents in the same directory as my index.html and the page is still refreshed, showing a new url. Thus, when at index.html and I click on m1, the url changes to /m1.html, not something like index.html#m1 (or something similar to that). The examples provided on jquerymobile do not make this clear. Have you any other examples to share?

Comment: I think you might be right... and my expectations are wrong... I notice when at m1, and I click on the Menu tag (which references "#") it correctly goes back to the index page. I need to investigate further, for example, how to apply events like click() to the newly added DOM content. Let me test some more...

Comment: Are my expectations wrong? I expected scripts loaded within index.html would be available after I clicked on my m1 link - thus, I expected the m1 page to be inserted into the DOM like a multi page would be hosted. I'm not getting m1 inserted, nor are any of the scripts loaded from index.html available which leads me to believe that my m1 page is treated as an external instead of internal page.

Comment: @fiprojects, your expectations are correct. External page should be loaded into current DOM and all existing scripts from Index should be available. Can you create a plunker (https://plnkr.co/) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: @fiprojects, here is a plunker i made: https://plnkr.co/edit/q3Dgaq02DxYjiqa6O9fF?p=preview

Comment: I'm not familiar with plnkr - and the demo does not work on Windows desktop Firefox 48.0.2. Console repors "Blocked loading mixed active content" for jq, jqm and jqm css. I will try resolve... just thought I would share an update. Thanks.